# Ошибка при объединении кода

Tags: c

Доброго времени суток!

Подскажите, в чем ошибка, компилятор ругается

```
#include <vcl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma hdrstop

/*
    1.Упорядочить список студентов по среднему баллу и вывести весь список. 
    2.Вывести анкетные данные студентов, получивших по предмету физика оценку "неудовлетворительно"
*/

#pragma argsused

const int N = 4;        // count students

struct stud {
    char name[15];
    char name2[15];
    int dayborn;
    int month;
    int yearborn;
    char group[10];
    int ball[5];
    float SredBall;
    int physicsBall;
    int CountEx;
};
s[N], tmp;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, j, k, m;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("Enter first name of %dst student ", i + 1);
        scanf("%15s", &s[i].name);
        printf("Enter second name ");
        scanf("%15s", &s[i].name2);
        printf("Enter day of borning ");
        scanf("%10d", &s[i].dayborn);
        printf("Enter month of borning ");
        scanf("%10d", &s[i].month);
        printf("Enter year of borning ");
        scanf("%10d", &s[i].yearborn);
        printf("Enter its group ");
        scanf("%10s", &s[i].group);
        printf("Vvedite kolichestvo predmetov ");
        scanf("%1d", &m);
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            printf("Enter its ball for %dst predmet ", j + 1);
            scanf("%3d", &s[i].ball[j]);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            sum = sum + s[i].ball[j];
        }
        s[i].SredBall = (float)sum / m;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        for (j = i + 1; j < N; j++)
            if (s[i].SredBall < s[j].SredBall) {
                tmp = s[i];
                s[i] = s[j];
                s[j] = tmp;
            }

    printf("%-26s %-13s %-8s %s", "Name", "Date", "group", "SredBall\n");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        printf("%-10s %-15s %02d.%02d.%-7d %-8s %.2f\n", s[i].name,
               s[i].name2, s[i].dayborn, s[i].month, s[i].yearborn,
               s[i].group, s[i].SredBall);

    int k, i, j;
    k = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("Enter quantity of exams\n");
        scanf("%d", &s[i].CountEx);
        getchar();

        printf("Enter his ball on physics\n");
        scanf("%d", &s[i].physics_ball);

        printf("Enter his balls on other subjects\n");
        for (j = 0; j < s[i].CountEx - 1; j++) {
            printf("Enter his %d-st ball\n", j + 1);
            scanf("%d", &s[i].ball[j]);
        }
    }
    int r = 0;
    while (r < 40) {
        printf("\n");
        r++;
    }
    printf("%-26s %-13s %-8s %s", "Name", "Date", "Ball on physics",
           "Other balls\n");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        printf("%-10s %-15s %02d.%02d.%-7d %-8s %.2f\n", s[i].name,
               s[i].name2, s[i].dayborn, s[i].month, s[i].yearborn,
               s[i].group, s[i].physics_ball);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Students whose ball on physics is hasn't handed over:");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (s[i].physics_ball < 3)
            printf("%-8s%-12s", s[i].name, s[i].name2);
        else
            k += 1;
    if (k == n)
        printf(" None");
    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

В начале написаны 2 задачи. Сначала был написан код 1 задачи, и она работала отлично. Но теперь хочу объединить 1 и 2 задачи, чтобы выводил весь список студентов, а ниже 2 таблицы (по 1 и 2 задачи). 2 отдельно написана была, но при совмещении ошибки.

Comment: @smthelse, Код должен форматироваться (кнопка 101010), а метка отражать язык программирования, иначе вопросы будут удаляться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так, должно работать:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma hdrstop

const int N = 4; // count students

struct stud {
    char name[15];
    char name2[15];
    int dayborn;
    int month;
    int yearborn;
    char group[10];
    int ball[5];
    float SredBall;
    int physicsBall;
    int CountEx;
} s[N], tmp;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int i, j, k, m;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("Enter first name of %dst student ", i + 1);
        scanf("%15s", (char *) &s[i].name);
        printf("Enter second name ");
            scanf("%15s", (char *) &s[i].name2);
        printf("Enter day of borning ");
        scanf("%10d", &s[i].dayborn);
        printf("Enter month of borning ");
        scanf("%10d", &s[i].month);
        printf("Enter year of borning ");
        scanf("%10d", &s[i].yearborn);
        printf("Enter its group ");
        scanf("%10s", (char *) &s[i].group);
        printf("Vvedite kolichestvo predmetov ");
        scanf("%1d", &m);
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            printf("Enter its ball for %dst predmet ", j + 1);
            scanf("%3d", &s[i].ball[j]);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            sum = sum + s[i].ball[j];
        }
        s[i].SredBall = (float) sum / m;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        for (j = i + 1; j < N; j++)
            if (s[i].SredBall < s[j].SredBall) {
                tmp = s[i];
                s[i] = s[j];
                s[j] = tmp;
            }

    printf("%-26s %-13s %-8s %s", "Name", "Date", "group", "SredBall\n");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        printf("%-10s %-15s %02d.%02d.%-7d %-8s %.2f\n", s[i].name, s[i].name2, s[i].dayborn, s[i].month, s[i].yearborn, s[i].group, s[i].SredBall);

    k = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("Enter quantity of examsn");
        scanf("%d", &s[i].CountEx);
        getchar();

        printf("Enter his ball on physics\n");
        scanf("%d", &s[i].physicsBall);

        printf("Enter his balls on other subjects\n");
        for (j = 0; j < s[i].CountEx - 1; j++) {
            printf("Enter his %d-st ball\n", j + 1);
            scanf("%d", &s[i].ball[j]);
        }
    }
    int r = 0;
    while (r < 40) {
        printf("n");
        r++;
    }
    printf("%-26s %-13s %-8s %s", "Name", "Date", "Ball on physics", "Other ballsn");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        printf("%-10s %-15s %02d.%02d.%-7d %-8s %.2fn", s[i].name, s[i].name2, s[i].dayborn, s[i].month, s[i].yearborn, s[i].group, s[i].physicsBall);
    printf("n");
    printf("Students whose ball on physics is hasn't handed over:");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        if (s[i].physicsBall < 3)
            printf("%-8s%-12s", s[i].name, s[i].name2);
        else k += 1;
    if (k == N) printf(" None");
    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: спасибо,работает